# How do you auto-place the ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK projects from CMake into a Visual Studio filter

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

So I understand that to create filters from CMake for a Visual Studio project, you use the [`source_group()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/source_group.html) command (which only works in combination with [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html))

But this way wants a expects a list of files to be included. I'm not the most expert at CMake yet to know all the files that the ALL_BUILD or ZERO_CHECK projects will include.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else curious I found the answer.

In the CMakeLists.txt add the following commands:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "CustomTargets")
```

Now the ALL_BUILD, ZERO_CHECK, and even INSTALL projects will all be placed in a Visual Studio Filter called CMakePredefinedTargets

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a `CMakePredefinedTargets` folder with:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
```

You can assign your name to this folder with:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "_CMakePredefinedTargets")
```